# How is Classic ASP handled in Windows Server 2012 vs. 2008?

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I moved some Classic ASP sites from Windows Server 2003-32 to 2008-64. 
It required few adjustments. All is running smoothly. 
Now I'm moving these same Classic ASP sites to Windows Server 2012-64.
Are there any big differences [in respect to running Classic ASP] between 2008 and 2012 I need to know about? 
It seems like 2008 maintained much backwards compatibility with Classic ASP and I want to make sure 2012 still supports Classic ASP as well. 
Primarily I'm looking for suggestions as to any IIS settings I need to change. Luckily, I'm not depending on any 3rd party components. Note: I'm using CLSupload, which is merely some functions that rely on Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library 2.5.

Comment: I have done some similar migrations and have found the 2008 to 2012 change to be trouble-free (unlike the 2003 to 2008 change).

Comment: I've migrated some asp classic applications from IIS7 64 bit (Windows 7 Pro) to IIS8 64 bit (Server 2012) recently without any issues.